# Change Order to Ascending from Alphabetical Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have json data being fetched word a wordpress plog using a controller.  It's displaying the categories alphabetical but I'd rather have it display is ascending order.  Is there a simple way to do this?

I'm new to angularjs (and javascript in general).

My HTML is:

```
<ion-list>
  <div class="list cat">
    <a ng-repeat="category in categories"
       href="#/category/{{category.id}}"
       class="item item-thumbnail-left catthumb">

        <img ng-src="{{category.acf.thumbnail.url}}" class="catthumb">
        <span style="font-size: 21px; font-weight: 400;">{{category.name}}</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: can you post your samlpe JSON data? and what you are using to display the data

Comment: Added the URL from the JSON data and basic html on how I'm getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter in your repeat:

```
<a ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy:'id'"
```

Use `orderBy:'id':true` if you want to reverse it.